# Document library view filter not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view, modern-experience, filter

I have 3 columns:

- Type (choice field)
- Comments (text field)
- Status (yes/no)

I need documents in my library to show in this view if the type is "choice 1", the comment column is empty and the status column is checked.

But the document should stay if the comment column is filled in and the status is checked. The document should only drop off the view if the comment column is filled in and the status column is unchecked.

How can I make this view work?

Comment: Comments column is single line of text or multiple lines of text? You can ignore the filter on comment column and just add filters on another 2 columns. Will that work for you?

Comment: single line of text. the comment column must be filled in if the type is "choice 1" and must stay in the view if the status is yes. I don't want a user to uncheck the status without the comment column filled in. That document must stay in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint document libary
2. Click on **Switch view options** (All Documents) drop down from top right corner and select **Edit current view**:

   [image]
3. Configure filters like below and then click **OK** at the bottom of view settings page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! There's no way to ensure the document doesn't fall off if someone makes the status 'no' and the comment column is empty?